# How to give a HTML "A" tag act as a submit button

Tags: html, css

I am creating a contact form that needs a submit button but I need it to be a certain look. I need to know if there is a way to assign a form action to an `A` tag in html so I can submit a form with the anchor tag.

Comment: What kind of styling are you applying to the anchor that can't be applied to a submit button?

Comment: just style your submit input as you wish

Comment: The button has to be positioned outside of the `<form>` tags.

Comment: Then use CSS to move it, or widen the scope of your `<form>` tag.

Comment: or wrap a bigger part of your document with the form , so submit stands in it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use Javascript to do this:

### Edit:

As some users have pointed out, using inline JS is bad practice, so I will use jQuery instead.

```
<form id="myForm">
    <a class="submit" href="#">Submit</a>
</form>
```

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("a.submit").click(function(){
        document.getElementById("myForm").submit();
    }); 
});
```

Here is your updated [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wG4xW/5/)

Comment: Would I be able to send this to a php script?

Comment: You mean post it? Yes.

Comment: What would I put in the `$_POST['']`;

Comment: All that I am doing here is essentially recreating the submit button using an `<a>` tag. This will post whatever you have in your inputs. Note that `<a>` is NOT an input and so it has no value, but if you have other inputs, you will use the name attribute: e.g. `<input type="text" name="myText">` will be retrieved with `$_POST["myText"]`

Comment: Can you take a look at my code and tell me If this will work? http://jsfiddle.net/wG4xW/

Comment: Please don’t recommend inline event handlers.

Comment: The `<a>` is outside of the `<form>` tags

Comment: your form needs an id in order to have your submit function working, and even then , this can be any tag as soon as you use the js onclick event, so a button or a poor lonely submit input :) your form can wrap the all page it would be less bad (can i say that this way ?) .. so no js needed

Comment: I think I'm not getting this because I'm really tired but let me try to. If I have a submit out side of the form it can still submit the information inside of the form?

Comment: @minitech I would have to use jQuery otherwise.

Comment: What do I put in the php post element?

Comment: @minitech That better?

Comment: @David: Why would you have to use jQuery? Just set the `onclick` property.

Comment: I have everything now except what I have to put in the post element.

Comment: @KronoFiles your elements' names are "name" and "email", so you retrieve them with $_POST["name"] and $_POST["email"]

Comment: @minitech I guess I wouldn't *have* to use jQuery, but I like jQuery for handling non-inline events. Is that better? Can you remove your downvote?

Comment: Because someone did, and you commented...Actually two people did

Comment: Well, I didn’t. (I was going to, though. Thanks for making a note!)

Comment: @David, I downvoted because this is bad advice. The best javascript one can write is none. The less of it there is, the easier it is to debug. There's no need for it in this case, so suggesting a solution that uses it is a poor choice.

Comment: the `a` tag requires the `href` attribute specified so that it looks like a link, otherwise it's just a normal text. I think we should mimic the link using button as other answers pointed out.

Comment: @KingKing I used an `<a>` because that is what the OP asked for. That's the only reason. Otherwise I totally agree with you.

Comment: @zzzzBov In order to use an `<a>` that submits the form, Javascript **is required**. Unless you can show me another solution that uses an `<a>` and doesn't use JS.

Comment: The fact here is that I totally agree with everyone here, **I'm just saying** that the OP asked for an **`<a>`** tag solution.

Comment: @David, [this is a classic example of an XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem), because OP is asking for information regarding a proposed solution, rather than his actual problem. Giving someone what they ask for can be detrimental in the long run.

Comment: @zzzzBov fair enough. But in this case, I don't see the error in giving the OP what he asked for. The solution *does work*. The only drawback that I can think of is if someone has JS disabled.

Comment: I have JS disabled =]

Comment: @David, so, as the `<a>` element is missing a `[href]` attribute, and doesn't have a `[tabindex]` attribute, how do you expect a user that's making use of assisted navigation to focus your poorly hacked version of a submit button? What happens when they navigate to next link? How do you expect to force the form to enable implicit submission? You're missing a lot of native features that you don't even realize are important.

Comment: if the idea was to have a submit look like a link , here it goes http://jsfiddle.net/xu6FJ/ javascript or jQuery are the same, same bad practice

Answer (score 1):

You may be better off using `<button>Your text here</button>`. This will render by default in most browsers as a button, but you can override this with CSS to render as a link.

This will negate the need for JavaScript and will preserve default browser behavior for a submit button like automatically submitting the form when pressing the enter key.

Answer (score 1):

You should use a real submit button (`<button>` or `<input type="submit">`) and style it so that it looks like a link.

If it *really* has to be outside of the form element for some reason, at least use [the standard HTML5 attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/Input#attr-form):

```
<form id="my-form">
    …
</form>
…
<input type="submit" value="Submit the form" form="my-form">
```

Then you can add a JavaScript-based fallback for browsers that don’t support it:

```
if (!('form' in document.createElement('input'))) {
    document.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
        var form = e.getAttribute('form');

        if (e.nodeName === 'input' && e.type === 'submit' && form) {
            document.getElementById(form).submit();
            e.preventDefault();
        }
    }, false);
}
```

Comment: be careful if you're using this fallback. It will work in this case because only the `<input type="submit">` element is outside of the form, but if there are other fields that are external to the `<form>` element, you'll need to use a more involved polyfill.

Comment: @zzzzBov: Definitely. It’s just a fallback for this specific case.

Answer (score 0):

If you need your submit button to look like a link, you should still use an `<input type="submit"/>` element or `<button type="submit">` element.

This is particularly important for users with assisted navigation, where form controls will often react differently from link elements. As you're interested in making the submit button **appear** as though it's a link, the task should be done with CSS.

<sub>HTML:</sub>

```
<form>
    ...other fields...
    <input type="submit" value="This looks like a link" class="linkish"/>
</form>
```

<sub>CSS:</sub>

```
.linkish {
    background-color: transparent;
    border: 0;
    color: blue;
    cursor: pointer;
    display: inline;
    margin: 0;
    outline: none;
    padding: 0;
    text-decoration: underline;
}
```

All you have to do is remove the styles that the browser's native submit button uses, and add the link styles.

[demo on jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qE5L2/)